# Instagram lower the quality of pictures

Tags: image, post, size, instagram, resolution

### i am an instagram influencer and All my post is Is a written explanation, when i post a pic Instagram reduces it quality!

- Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

That is not really a question, but it is very possible. I suggest you read this https://innov8tiv.com/fix-instagram-keeps-reducing-quality-photos-iphone-poor-image-quality-instagram/. A bit outdated but it may help you.

Comment: thanks for ur help, but I haven't benefited anything from this article